# How can I make a menu system with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I put the menu on the left with tkinter. As I click on these menus, I want def to come inside. But in the code I made, the contents of def overlap.

After I click, I want whatever is there to be cleared and then clicked.

How can I do it?

[image]

```
def GenelGorunum():
    baslik = Label(text="Genel Görünüm")
    baslik.grid(row=1, column=4)

def Test():
    baslik = Label(text="Sınıf Yönetimi")
    baslik.grid(row=1, column=4)
    
menubuton1 = Button(text="Genel Görünüm", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=2, command=GenelGorunum)
menubuton2 = Button(text="Sınıf Yönetimi", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=2, command=Test)
```

***Edit:***

[image]

@acw1668 I hope this time I can **explain**:

**Episode 1:** Text, Button,
**Episode 2:** Button,
**Episode 3:** Text.

When I move from Part 1 to 2, I want nothing from 1 to be left. I just want the part 2 to stay. Is an example.

**Current code:**

```
def GenelGorunum():
    baslik.config(text="Genel Görünüm")
    aciklama.config(text="Selam agalar")

def Test():
    baslik.config(text="Sınıf Yönetimi")
    aciklama.config(text="dasd")
    btn.config(text="Selam")


baslik = Label(fg="white", bg="black")
baslik.grid(row=1, column=4)

aciklama = Label(fg="white", bg="black")
aciklama.grid(row=2, column=4)

btn = Button(bg="red")
btn.grid(row=2, column=4)

menubuton1 = Button(text="Genel Görünüm", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=2, command=GenelGorunum)
menubuton2 = Button(text="Sınıf Yönetimi", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=2, command=Test)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Side Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858214/tkinter-side-bar)

Comment: @TheLizzard no not on the link you posted. I took care of the menu completely. But I want to manage when I press the buttons from the menu. I marked it with the `command`, but they overlap. When I click on something, I want the old one to go and the new one to come.

Comment: Oh, ok. Have you tried putting them in a frame and then using `.grid_forget()` or just calling `.grid_forget()` on the buttons that you don't need? Also can you post some working code that shows the problem?

Comment: @TheLizzard I don't fully understand `.grid_forget()`. Can you send me a sample code? For me to learn. Sorry if I tried.

Comment: `.grid_forget()` basically removes the widget from scree, that's all, but it keeps all the info about the widget

Comment: @Matiiss Can you give information about how to use it?

Comment: just when you want to remove a widget from the screen You use it, it's that simple

Comment: `def Test(): baslik = Label(text="Sınıf Yönetimi") baslik.grid(row=1, column=2) baslik.grid_forget() `

I do but it doesn't work.

Comment: @EmirBolat Try calling `baslik.grid_forget()` first. Calling it just after `baslik.grid(...)` cancels out the 2 statements

Comment: Why don't you create the label once and then update its content inside those functions?

Comment: @acw1668 I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @EmirBolat See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the label once and update its content inside those functions:

```py
def GenelGorunum():
    baslik.config(text="Genel Görünüm")
    aciklama.config(text="Selam agalar")
    btn.grid_remove()  # hide the button

def Test():
    baslik.config(text="Sınıf Yönetimi")
    aciklama.config(text="dasd")
    btn.grid(row=3, column=4) # show the button

baslik = Label(fg="white", bg="black")
baslik.grid(row=1, column=4)

aciklama = Label(fg="white", bg="black")
aciklama.grid(row=2, column=4)

btn = Button(text="Selam", bg="red")
#btn.grid(row=2, column=4)  # initially hide the button

menubuton1 = Button(text="Genel Görünüm", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=2, command=GenelGorunum)
menubuton2 = Button(text="Sınıf Yönetimi", fg="white", bg="#282528", height=2, command=Test)
```

Comment: I made the code you sent. But again there was a problem.

`def GenelGorunum():
    baslik.config(text="Genel Görünüm")
    aciklama.config(text="Selam agalar")
    btn.grid_remove()

def Test():
    baslik.config(text="Sınıf Yönetimi")
    aciklama.config(text="dasd")

    btn.config(text="Selam")


baslik = Label(fg="white", bg="black")
baslik.grid(row=1, column=4)

aciklama = Label(fg="white", bg="black")
aciklama.grid(row=2, column=4)

btn = Button(bg="red")
btn.grid(row=2, column=4)`

I did it. I just want the button to work in `test`, but it works in `GenelGorunum`.

Comment: Don't post long code in comment.  Put it in your question as an update.  what do you mean *"want the button to work in test, but it works in GenelGorunum"*.

Comment: I did not know because I was new, Sorry.

I want these articles, buttons and many elements to work only in certain areas. For example, the button appears only in the `test`, but not in the `GenelGorunum` section. I want to do it like this.

Comment: `test` and `GenelGorunum` are functions, not areas in the window.  So I still don't get what you want.

Comment: I am using translation, you may not understand this. I want to:

I want certain elements in the menus to be specific to that category only. It's like a normal menu and the contents. For example, I want the `buton` to appear only in the `test`. But when I pass my `GenelGorunum` from the `test`, the button still stays.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it as you said more or less the same.  May be you create another question so that other professionals can help.

Comment: Please read [image](https://www.hizliresim.com/hpb3yqw)