# Tkinter Error, _tkinter.TclError: can't delete Tcl command

Tags: tkinter

I started Working on a beauty Salon Management system, everything seems so be working fine till now but In the admin Panel, I created an animated Navigation sidebar and every time i close the page, I get the "can't delete TCL command". Any Thoughts on this? Also any tips and opinion on the code would be highly appreciated.

Full Error:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2306, in destroy
    Misc.destroy(self)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 632, in destroy
    self.tk.deletecommand(name)
_tkinter.TclError: can't delete Tcl command
```

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *

import setuptools.command.alias
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class AdminPage:
    def __init__(self):

        # Creating main window
        self.adminPageWindow = Tk()
        self.adminPageWindow.bind("<Escape>", self.minimizeScreen)
        self.adminPageWindow.bind("<F11>", self.maximizeScreen)
        self.adminPageWindow.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.adminPageWindow.config( bg="#FFFFFF")

        # Creating Nav Bar
        # Creating default Vars
        self.min_w = 50  # Minimum width of the frame
        self.max_w = 135  # Maximum width of the frame
        self.cur_width = self.min_w  # Increasing width of the frame
        self.expanded = False  # Check if it is completely expanded

        # Creating the Images from existing files
        self.logoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ('Resources/Images/Logo.png').resize ((30, 30), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.dashboard_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ('Resources/Images/Dashboard_img.png').resize ((40, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ('Resources/Images/New_img.png').resize ((40, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.stock_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ('Resources/Images/stock_img.png').resize ((40, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.pay_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ('Resources/Images/pay_img.png').resize ((40, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.profile_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ('Resources/Images/profile_img.png').resize ((40, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS))

        self.adminPageWindow.update ()

        self.navbar = Frame (self.adminPageWindow, width=50, height=self.adminPageWindow.winfo_height (), bg="#FEF17D")
        self.navbar.pack(side=LEFT)

        # Creating Corresponding
        self.dashboard_button = Button(self.navbar,image=self.dashboard_img,bg='#FEF17D',relief='flat', command=self.dashboardPage)
        self.new_button = Button(self.navbar, image=self.new_img, bg="#FEF17D", relief='flat')
        self.stock_button = Button(self.navbar, image=self.stock_img, bg="#FEF17D", relief='flat')
        self.pay_button = Button(self.navbar, image=self.pay_img, bg="#FEF17D", relief='flat')
        self.profile_button = Button(self.navbar, image=self.profile_img, bg="#FEF17D", relief='flat')

        self.emptyLabel = Label(self.navbar, image=self.logoImage, bg="#FEF17D").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)
        self.dashboard_button.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=40)
        self.new_button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=40)
        self.stock_button.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=40)
        self.pay_button.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=40)
        self.profile_button.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=40)

        self.navbar.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: self.expand())
        self.navbar.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: self.contract())
        self.navbar.grid_propagate(False)

        self.headerFrame = Frame(self.adminPageWindow, bg="#FEF17D", height=50)
        self.headerFrame.pack(fill=X)

        self.mainFrame = Frame (self.adminPageWindow, bg="#FFFFFF", width=self.adminPageWindow.winfo_width () - 50 ,height=self.adminPageWindow.winfo_height () - 150)
        self.mainFrame.pack()
        self.footerFrame = Frame(self.adminPageWindow, bg="#FFFFFF", width=self.adminPageWindow.winfo_width()-50, height=50)
        self.footerFrame.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)

        self.headerFrameLabel = Label(self.headerFrame, text="Admin Panel", font=("Courier New Italic Bold", 18), bg="#FEF17D")
        self.headerFrameLabel.pack(anchor=CENTER, pady=5)
        text = "Salon Management System V1.00\nCreated by Nael Ghannam"
        self.footerFrameLabel = Label(self.footerFrame, text=text, font=("Courier New Italic", 10), bg="#FFFFFF")
        self.footerFrameLabel.pack()




        self.adminPageWindow.mainloop()

    def minimizeScreen(self, event):
        self.adminPageWindow.attributes ('-fullscreen', False)
        window_Width = 1280
        window_height = 720

        screenWidth = self.adminPageWindow.winfo_screenwidth ()
        screen_Height = self.adminPageWindow.winfo_screenheight ()

        position_top = int (screen_Height / 2 - window_height / 2)
        position_right = int (screenWidth / 2 - window_Width / 2)

        self.adminPageWindow.geometry (f"{window_Width}x{window_height}+{position_right}+{position_top}")
        return None
    def maximizeScreen(self, event):
        self.adminPageWindow.attributes ('-fullscreen', True)
        return None
    def expand(self):
        self.cur_width += 10  # Increase the width by 10
        rep = self.adminPageWindow.after (5, self.expand)  # Repeat this func every 5 ms
        self.navbar.config (width=self.cur_width)  # Change the width to new increase width
        if self.cur_width >= self.max_w:  # If width is greater than maximum width
            self.expanded = True  # Frame is expended
            self.adminPageWindow.after_cancel (rep)  # Stop repeating the func
            self.fill()
    def contract(self):
        self.cur_width -= 10  # Reduce the width by 10
        rep = self.adminPageWindow.after (5, self.contract)  # Call this func every 5 ms
        self.navbar.config (width=self.cur_width)  # Change the width to new reduced width
        if self.cur_width <= self.min_w:  # If it is back to normal width
            self.expanded = False  # Frame is not expanded
            self.navbar.after_cancel (rep)  # Stop repeating the func
            self.fill()
    def fill(self):
        if self.expanded:  # If the frame is exanded
            # Show a text, and remove the image
            self.dashboard_button.config (text='Dashboard', image='', font=("Courier New Italic", 14))
            self.new_button.config (text='New Entries', image='', font=("Courier New Italic", 14))
            self.stock_button.config (text='Stock', image='', font=("Courier New Italic", 14))
            self.pay_button.config (text='Pay', image='', font=("Courier New Italic", 14))
            self.profile_button.config (text='Profiles', image='', font=("Courier New Italic", 14))
        else:
            # Bring the image back
            self.dashboard_button.config (image=self.dashboard_img, font=(0, 21))
            self.new_button.config (image=self.new_img, font=(0, 21))
            self.stock_button.config (image=self.stock_img, font=(0, 21))
            self.pay_button.config (image=self.pay_img, font=(0, 21))
            self.profile_button.config (image=self.profile_img, font=(0, 21))

    def dashboardPage(self):
        self.headerFrameLabel.config(text="Dashboard")


AdminPage()
```

Comment: [Have a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166640/interactive-and-nice-looking-buttons-in-tkinter/68167482#68167482). I have implemented this on buttons but you can do it for Frames

Comment: Can you please post the full error traceback? Also CoolCloud implemented something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66859503/11106801)

Comment: To start with you should change `self.adminPageWindow.update ()` to `self.adminPageWindow.update_idletasks()`. That will give `tkinter` time to process all those images.

Comment: @Derek `.update()` will also give `tkinter` time to process all of those images. `.update()` does everything that `.update_idletasks()` does and more. It can also handle events so if you aren't careful it can cause `RecursionError`s.

Comment: @TheLizzard they are similar but not exactly the same. `update_idletasks` will enter event loop until all idle callbacks have been called. This will update the display of windows but not process events caused by the user. This can affect the geometry manager so that `Tk` or `Toplevel` may not complete there initialization.

Comment: @Derek Yes (depends on what what you mean by *update the display of windows*). So we can agree that `.update()` does everything that `.update_idletasks()` does and a few other things (like events created by the user). So why did you suggest OP to change `self.adminPageWindow.update()` to `self.adminPageWindow.update_idletasks()`? In that case I don't changing it would help.

Comment: @TheLizzard I suggested it because of the large number of images being loaded and the possibility of user events causing problems. All though this maybe just a side issue and may not address the main problem.

Comment: @Derek Just because I was curious I tested how long the `.update()` runs for. It turns out that it only runs for `0.0783` seconds. I think the images get loaded in to memory when OP calls `ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)`. But as a safety precaution, you are right using `.update_idletasks()` is safer.

Comment: @Derek I tried both .update() and .update_idletasks() and Nothing Changed, but thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: @TheLizzard    I Added the full stack error.

Comment: @NG18 I have no clue why this works for me but try adding: `self.adminPageWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.adminPageWindow.destroy)`. I just guessed and it worked for me :D.

Comment: @TheLizzard where do I add it? And can you please explain the syntax?

Comment: @NG18 Try adding it just after the `self.adminPageWindow = Tk()`.

Comment: @TheLizzard If this is the case I take it back and I'm sorry, I'm still intermediate in tkinter programming and the unexplained syntax at first sounded fishy, especially since it did not work and it included the destroy function. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @NG18 It's fine. With more testing my solution doesn't actually work. I have seen this problem before and something similar solved it last time so I assumed that it will solve it this time. I will try to work out another solution.

Comment: @TheLizzard Much appreciated. Any comments on the code in overall?

Comment: @NG18 Think I found a working solution. I will write an answer and let you test it. Overall your code is good. It looks better than my code :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `expand` and your `contract` function to this:

```py
def expand(self):
    self.cur_width += 10  # Increase the width by 10
    self.navbar.config(width=self.cur_width)  # Change the width to new increase width
    if self.cur_width >= self.max_w:  # If width is greater than maximum width
        self.expanded = True  # Frame is expended
        self.fill()
    else:
        rep = self.adminPageWindow.after(5, self.expand)  # Repeat this func every 5 ms

def contract(self):
    self.cur_width -= 10  # Reduce the width by 10
    self.navbar.config(width=self.cur_width)  # Change the width to new reduced width
    if self.cur_width <= self.min_w:  # If it is back to normal width
        self.expanded = False  # Frame is not expanded
        self.fill()
    else:
        rep = self.adminPageWindow.after(5, self.contract)  # Call this func every 5 ms
```

You will notice that I moved the code around so you never have to call `after_cancel`. I think the problem is that `after_cancel` cancels the `.after` script but `tkinter` doesn't remove it from it's memory so it again tries to delete it when you close the window. From what I can see, it might be a bug in `tkinter`.