# Tkinter Error: _tkinter.TclError: can't delete Tcl command on Tkinter root with a Custom Toplevel

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem with an error **_tkinter.TclError: can't delete Tcl command** when trying to root.destroy(). Reason I am using a CustomToplvl widget is because I plan to place all my other widget(s) only once in a pop-up window and hide it when user close the pop-up window (this includes stopping all .after() events which are bound to the toplevel when window is closed). But, **after closing** the toplevel window, I **cannot destroy the root window**.

Here is the CustomToplvl code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

def type_int(arg):
    if (type(arg)) == int or (isinstance(arg, np.integer) == True):
        return True
    else:
        return False

class CustomToplvl(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, toplvl_title = 'Toplevel', min_w = None, min_h = None, icon_img = None
        , topmost_bool = False
        , *args, **kwargs):
        #   initialisation of the Toplevel
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent

        self.title(toplvl_title)

        if (min_w is not None) and (min_h is not None):
            if type_int(min_w) == True and type_int(min_h) == True:
                self.minsize(width=max(0, min_w), height=max(0, min_h))
            else:
                raise TypeError("'min_w' and 'min_h' has to be an int-type value.")
        
        """Use tk.Frame widget as the after event proxy. self.__tk_after_proxy is used track & trace after event(s) which are 'bound' to CustomToplvl"""
        self.__tk_after_proxy = tk.Frame(self, width = 1, height = 1, bd = 0)
        self.__tk_after_proxy.place(x = 0, y = 0, relx = 1 , rely = 1
            , anchor = 'nw')
        self.__tk_after_proxy.lower()
        self.__tk_after_id = int(0)
        self.__local_after_events = []

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        self.bind('<Map>', partial(self.__topmost_event))

        self.withdraw()

        self.__open_bool = False

        self.__topmost_bool = topmost_bool

        self.__topmost_status = False

        try:
            self.iconphoto(False, icon_img)
        except Exception:
            pass

        self.update_idletasks()

    def __topmost_event(self, event):
        window_state = str(self.wm_state())
        if window_state == 'normal':
            if self.__topmost_bool == True:
                if self.__topmost_status == False:
                    self.lift()
                    self.attributes('-topmost', True)
                    self.__topmost_status = True
            else:
                self.__topmost_status = False
                self.attributes('-topmost', False)

        elif window_state == 'zoomed':
            if self.__topmost_bool == True:
                if self.__topmost_status == True:
                    self.attributes('-topmost', False)
                    self.__topmost_status = False
            else:
                self.__topmost_status = False
                self.attributes('-topmost', False)

    def check_open(self):
        return self.__open_bool

    def open(self):
        self.deiconify()
        self.__open_bool = True
        if self.__topmost_bool == True:
            if self.__topmost_status == False:
                self.lift()
                self.attributes('-topmost', True)
                self.__topmost_status = True
        else:
            self.__topmost_status = False
            self.attributes('-topmost', False)

    def show(self):
        window_state = str(self.wm_state())
        if window_state == 'normal':
            self.__open_bool = True
            if self.__topmost_bool == True:
                if self.__topmost_status == False:
                    self.lift()
                    self.attributes('-topmost', True)
                    self.__topmost_status = True
            else:
                self.__topmost_status = False
                self.attributes('-topmost', False)

        elif window_state == 'zoomed':
            self.__open_bool = True
            if self.__topmost_bool == True:
                if self.__topmost_status == True:
                    self.attributes('-topmost', False)
                    self.__topmost_status = False
            else:
                self.__topmost_status = False
                self.attributes('-topmost', False)

        else:
            self.deiconify()
            self.__open_bool = True
            if self.__topmost_bool == True:
                if self.__topmost_status == False:
                    self.lift()
                    self.attributes('-topmost', True)
                    self.__topmost_status = True
            else:
                self.__topmost_status = False
                self.attributes('-topmost', False)

    def close(self):
        self.withdraw()
        self.__open_bool = False

        # Stop all CustomToplvl after event(s) when closing the CustomToplvl window.
        for event_id in self.__local_after_events:
            self.after_cancel(event_id)

    def after(self, delay, func, *args):
        #Use tk.Frame widget as the after event proxy. This function is track & trace after event(s) which are 'bound' to CustomToplvl

        tk_thread_id = self.__tk_after_proxy.after(delay, func, *args)
        self.__local_after_events.append(tk_thread_id)
        all_after_events = list(self.tk.call('after', 'info')) # Will return ALL after events which are 'binded' to all existing widget(s).

        # Compare which after event(s) belong to CustomToplvl
        self.__local_after_events = [after_event for after_event in self.__local_after_events if after_event in all_after_events]

        return tk_thread_id


    def after_idle(self, delay, func, *args):
        #Use tk.Frame widget as the after event proxy. This function is track & trace after event(s) which are 'bound' to CustomToplvl

        tk_thread_id = self.__tk_after_proxy.after_idle(delay, func, *args)
        self.__local_after_events.append(tk_thread_id)
        all_after_events = list(self.tk.call('after', 'info')) # Will return ALL after events which are 'binded' to all existing widget(s).

        # Compare which after event(s) belong to CustomToplvl
        self.__local_after_events = [after_event for after_event in self.__local_after_events if after_event in all_after_events]
        return tk_thread_id
```

Here is my main function:

```
from tk_custom_toplvl import CustomToplvl

from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

def open_toplvl(tk_toplvl):
    if False == tk_toplvl.check_open():
        tk_after_event_2(tk_toplvl)

        tk_toplvl.open()
        screen_width = tk_toplvl.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = tk_toplvl.winfo_screenheight()
        x_coordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (300/2))
        y_coordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (200/2))
        tk_toplvl.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(300, 200, x_coordinate, y_coordinate))

    else:
        tk_toplvl.show()

def root_destroy(tk_root):
    tk_root.destroy()

def tk_after_event_1(widget):
    print("Tk Root After Event")
    widget.after(100, tk_after_event_1, widget)

def tk_after_event_2(widget):
    print("Tk Toplevel After Event")
    widget.after(100, tk_after_event_2, widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    root.minsize(width=600, height=450)
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    x_coordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (600/2))
    y_coordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (450/2))

    root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(600, 450, x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
    tk_after_event_1(root)

    # Initialize CustomToplvl class
    tk_toplvl = CustomToplvl(root, width = 300, height = 200, min_w = 300, min_h = 200, toplvl_title = 'Custom Toplevel', topmost_bool = True)

    open_toplvl_btn = tk.Button(root, text = 'Open Toplvl', relief = tk.GROOVE, font = 'Helvetica 12')
    open_toplvl_btn['command'] = partial(open_toplvl, tk_toplvl)

    open_toplvl_btn.place(x = 0, y = 0, relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'c')

    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", partial(root_destroy, tk_root = root))
    root.mainloop()
```

I have tried using the following in the main function to destroy the all toplevel widgets before destroying root. But the error still appears.

```
def root_destroy(tk_root):
    for widget in tk_root.winfo_children(): # Loop through each widget in main window
        if isinstance(widget,tk.Toplevel): # If widget is an instance of toplevel
            widget.destroy()
            
    tk_root.destroy()
```

Comment: It seems like that the issue is on using after proxy `self.__tk_after_proxy` and it is not necessary at all.  I don't know the exact cause of the issue, but removing the after proxy fixes the issue (you need to modify `CustomToplvl.after()` and `CustomToplvl.after_idle()` to not using the after proxy of course).

Comment: @acw1668 True removing them does prevent the Tcl error from occurring. However, the after event(s) would still be running in the background because CustomToplvl.close() just withdraw the toplevel window. I don't plan to .destroy() the toplevel window when i decide to close it because I would need to re-create all my toplevel children widget(s) again and that would be time-consuming. So, I was relying on it being destroyed when root.destroy() command is executed.

Comment: @acw1668 So my thought process was that `self.__tk_after_proxy` list is there to 'store' the CustomToplvl after event(s), so that I can stop them when I withdraw the window with CustomToplvl.close(). After some searching, perhaps it has something to do with after event(s) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234627/tkinter-error-tkinter-tclerror-cant-delete-tcl-command. If so, does allowing after event(s) to run when toplevel is withdrawn advisable? I just worried that too many after event(s) running in the background will slow down my tkinter app.

Comment: I just suggest to remove `self.__tk_after_proxy` (the frame), not `self.__local_after_events` (the list of after IDs).

Comment: @acw1668 Oh my goodness. Many apologies, my brain is not working. Yeah I tried out your suggestion, it seems to solve the issue. Thank you very much. Though I am curious as to why assigning an after event to a children in tk.Toplevel (in my case the frame `self.__tk_after_proxy` ) will cause the Tcl error.